# How can I manage the field order for the export function in Sitecore Forms?

Tags: sitecore-forms

The `Export to a CSV file` function of Sitecore Forms seems to set the field sort order randomly.  Does anyone know how I might set a specific field sort order?  Thanks

Answer (score 7):

#### SqlFormDataProvider

The order of the field is basically the order in which the fields were created. The genesis of the export is the `Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Client.Controllers.ExportDataController`. And this calls into the `Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Data.SqlServer.SqlFormDataProvider` provider.

The SQL that fetches the list is this.

```
List<FormEntry> formEntryList = new List<FormEntry>(this.SqlDataApi.CreateObjectReader<FormEntry>("SELECT {0}ID{1},{0}FormItemID{1},{0}Created{1} FROM {0}FormEntry{1} WHERE {0}FormItemID{1}={2}formItemId{3} AND {0}Created{1} BETWEEN {2}start{3} AND {2}end{3}", new object[6]
```

specifically `SELECT {0}ID{1},{0}FormItemID{1},{0}Created{1} FROM {0}FormEntry{1} WHERE {0}FormItemID{1}={2}formItemId{3} AND {0}Created{1} BETWEEN {2}start{3} AND {2}end{3}`

This just fetches them in the default SQL sort order which is the order the rows are in the table

[image]

The fix is to rewrite the class `Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Data.SqlServer.SqlFormDataProvider`, which is the implementation  of `IFormDataProvider`. You can make this sort it any way you want, or what is possible. This class is registered in the config file `App_Config\Sitecore\ExperienceForms\Sitecore.ExperienceForms.config`.

```
<register serviceType="Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Data.IFormDataProvider, Sitecore.ExperienceForms" implementationType="Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Data.SqlServer.SqlFormDataProvider, Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Data.SqlServer" lifetime="Transient" />
```

#### The fields are incredibly dynamic

Now the real question is how would you get the sort or you want? Maybe a multilist setting or something that would allow you to do it in the editor. To me the real issue is that you can add and remove fields at will. And based on the date range you pick in your export, it fields the fields that were in place within that range. That makes it super difficult to allow you to know what fields to sort and when. Very dynamic.